# Create a numerical probability generator - Euromillions Generator

Tags: delphi-7

I'm asking for help. I'm looking to create a numerical probabilities generator but let me explain exactly the kind of help I´m asking to.
I've already came up with a source code that will randomly generate numbers, but I want to make some numbers with more chance to be generated than others.

So far I've got this, but this will only generate this numbers and here´s where my brain explodes. This code won´t distinguish the numbers, it doesn't generate a 12.. It generates either a 1 or 2.
I want to make it to "see" lets say.. a 1 a 2 and a 12

Please, help me on this one.

```
var
i: integer;
const
str = '0102030405060708091011121314151617181920212223242  526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950';
max = 5;
begin
Edit1.Text := '';
Randomize;
for i := 1 to max do
Edit1.Text := Edit1.Text + str[random(length(str))+1];
```

Sincerly,
Hopsins

Comment: This question would benefit a lot from being more precise with the mathematical language being used. As it stands it is not clear exactly what probability distribution you are wanting to create.

Comment: @shuttle87 To be honest, I'm trying to create an "Euromillion Generator". Well.. That should answer the question.

Comment: Toi get going, learn about **arrays**.  Load up an array with the numbers, and pick one randomly.  Then you'll have to learn about the **shuffle algorithm**.  Essentially, when you pick one, you have to delete it from the array so you don't pick it again.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To pull a number from `str`, you need two digits. To select '01', you would pull out the two characters starting at position #1.  For '02', you need to start at position #3. '03' starts at position #5.  You might want to use the expression:

```
copy ( str,  random ( length(str) div 2 ) * 2 + 1, 2  )
```

Here, `length(str)` is 100, `length(str) div 2` is 50. 
`random` generates a number from 0 through 49.
Multiply that by 2, and add 1, to get the index of the first character.
Then use `copy` to pull out two characters starting at that position.